# heroku db:pull errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

Well, I used to be able to `push` and `pull` with heroku, but it just asked me to upgrade taps, so I did. Once I did that I started getting errors that look like this when I attempt a `db:pull`

```
Receiving schema
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.21/bin/schema:3:
    in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)

    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.21/bin/schema:3
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.21/bin/schema:3:
    in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)

    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.21/bin/schema:3
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.21/bin/schema:3:
    in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)

    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.21/bin/schema:3

Schema:        100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:07
Receiving indexes
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.21/bin/schema:3:
in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.21/bin/schema:3
schema_migrat: 100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
Receiving data
3 tables, 600 records
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5/lib/sqlite3/errors.rb:62:
in `check': SQLite3::SQLException: PRIMARY KEY must be unique (Sequel::DatabaseError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5/lib/sqlite3/resultset.rb:56:in `check'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5/lib/sqlite3/resultset.rb:48:in `commence'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5/lib/sqlite3/resultset.rb:38:in `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:136:in `new'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:136:in `execute'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:232:in `execute_batch'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:163:in `prepare'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:231:in `execute_batch'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/sqlite.rb:130:in `_execute'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/logging.rb:28:in `log_yield'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/sqlite.rb:130:in `_execute'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:71:in `hold'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:226:in `synchronize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/sqlite.rb:117:in `_execute'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/sqlite.rb:87:in `execute_dui'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:552:in `execute_dui'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:243:in `import'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:243:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:243:in `import'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/query.rb:223:in `_transaction'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/query.rb:209:in `transaction'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:84:in `hold'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:226:in `synchronize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/query.rb:207:in `transaction'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:243:in `import'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.21/lib/taps/data_stream.rb:315:in `import_rows'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.21/lib/taps/data_stream.rb:142:in `fetch_remote'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.21/lib/taps/operation.rb:308:in `pull_data_from_table'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.21/lib/taps/operation.rb:301:in `loop'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.21/lib/taps/operation.rb:301:in `pull_data_from_table'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.21/lib/taps/operation.rb:284:in `pull_data'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.21/lib/taps/operation.rb:278:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.21/lib/taps/operation.rb:278:in `pull_data'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.21/lib/taps/operation.rb:253:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.21/lib/taps/operation.rb:203:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.21/lib/taps/operation.rb:203:in `catch_errors'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.21/lib/taps/operation.rb:246:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.21/lib/taps/cli.rb:171:in `clientxfer'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/heroku-1.19.1/lib/heroku/commands/db.rb:152:in `taps_client'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/heroku-1.19.1/lib/heroku/commands/db.rb:25:in `pull'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/heroku-1.19.1/lib/heroku/command.rb:49:in `send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/heroku-1.19.1/lib/heroku/command.rb:49:in `run_internal'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/heroku-1.19.1/lib/heroku/command.rb:21:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/heroku-1.19.1/bin/heroku:13
    from /usr/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/heroku:19
```

Eventually I ended up trying to upgrade everything in sight, including:
sequel
heroku
rubygems
and of course taps

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but I've decided to move on to RVM to a completely different install of Ruby etc, and that seems to be working just fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to restart my webrick server, gosh i feel dumb.